# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0)

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, upgrade, login, cm-redissession

I had this error message showing after I tried to upgrade the Magento 1.9.1 cm_redisSession from the magento connect interface:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(ma' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `SUM((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `lifetime`, `AVG((IFNULL(main_table.base_total_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_invoiced, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_invoiced, 0) - (IFNULL(main_table.base_total_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_tax_refunded, 0) - IFNULL(main_table.base_shipping_refunded, 0))) * main_table`.`base_to_global_rate)` AS `average` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.status NOT IN('canceled')) AND (main_table.state NOT IN('new', 'pending_payment'))";

Now I can't log in into the backend. Can you help me? What if I roll back a DB backup?

Comment: This has happened to me on a 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 upgrade. You can roll back the code, and it should work. What I've found is that the DB was fine, but the queries were constructed with incorrect encapsulations. I have no solution as this point.

Comment: roll back the code ? you mean a magento system backup ?

Comment: No, version control-revert. If you don't version-control, then you can try undoing the update. It was a code issue for me, not database.

Comment: Because i'm not expert in this kind of situation, could you please explain me how to do that reversion? i remember you that the problem started when i tried to upgrade the cm_redissession module and that now i cannot access the backend.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. It involves replacing `community/Cm/RedisSession` with earlier files you've had (and possibly some other files - I don't know).

Comment: Ok, i could replace the community/Cm/RedisSession folder with earlier files. There is no way to know which other file i've to replace ?

Comment: restore lib file your problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace app/code/core/Zend with a version from 1.9.2 CE

The error your seeing is on the dashboard, the rest of your admin will work except for the customer grid and the inability to reindex category/products

Comment: I'll try and tell you the result in the evening! thanks in the meanwhile

Comment: That worked! Thanks What do you mean with the customer grid and the inability to reindex category/products ?

Comment: Before you did the replacement of those files, I found reindexing and the customer grid were broken. Once those files were replaced it all becomes fixed.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me too!! But have not tested anything (like, basically all magento functions ie: add to cart, log in, edit account..etc..its a long list for both frontend & admin) . Keep in mind im updating to 1.9.2 form 1.7.

Comment: EDIT: index is completely locked with Stock "Status Index process is working now. Please try run this process later."..But customer grid works ok! Cleared cache as well.

Comment: Thanks to Alan Storm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127430/magento-indexes-issue-cant-reindex I can now reindex...woohoo!